# Writing values on Ox Oy axis in coordinate system

Tags: c++, graphics

In my program, I have already drawn the coordinate system, but I have trouble with writing values onto the Ox,Oy axis. What should I do in order to write the values on them ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include"graphics.h"

using namespace std;
const int WIDTH=800,HEIGHT=600;

void drawLine (int MovetoX,int MovetoY,int drawX,int drawY,int  color,int textX,int textY)
{          
    moveto(MovetoX,MovetoY);
    setcolor(color);
    lineto(drawX,drawY);
}
int main()
{
    drawLine(0,HEIGHT/2,WIDTH,HEIGHT/2,WHITE,WIDTH-20,HEIGHT/2+10);
    drawLine(WIDTH/2,0,WIDTH/2,HEIGHT,WHITE,WIDTH-20,HEIGHT/2+10);
}
```

I expect seeing the numerical values on Ox,Oy axis.

Comment: do you mean labeling axis with numbers?; what library is your graphics.h?
does it have some font rendering capabilities?

Comment: this looks like BGI ... but is missing the init ... so if the case I would try [outtextxy](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/outtextxy.html) ...

Comment: Thanks, I will try